# How to pause animation play state for everything except one div until the dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please be kind, I haven't made a post on here in forever but I have just now ran into an issue I'm looking for some quick help with. It should be really easy syntax/formatting that I'm just not familiar with and I'm struggling to find the correct answer.

Essentially, I am using the following CSS to pause the animation play state of everything on my page until the dom is fully loaded -

```
.js-loading * {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.js-loading *:before {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.js-loading *:after {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.qt-loading {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;    
}

#qt-loading-qtload001 > div {
  align-content: center;
  top: 50%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: -.5%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border: 6px solid;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: white;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-left-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: qt-loadanim001 1s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: -100000s;    
}

@keyframes qt-loadanim001 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

But I now have one div where I need the animation to NOT be paused until the dom is loaded (class 'qt-loading')... How would I make this CSS pause everything on my page EXCEPT 'qt-loading'? I would assume the :not selector, but I'm unsure how to combine that with my current CSS.

Thank you so so so much

Edit:

and for more context, here is the html / js

```
document.documentElement.className += " js-loading";

window.addEventListener("load", showPage, false);

function showPage() {
  document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace("js-loading","");
}

<div id="qt-loading-qtload001" class="qt-loading"> <div></div>
```

And this is the new CSS I have tried using the :not selector, but I could not get it to work -

```
.js-loading *:not(.qt-loading) {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.js-loading *:not(.qt-loading):before {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.js-loading *:not(.qt-loading):after {
  animation-play-state: paused !important;
}

.qt-loading {
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}

.qt-loading:before {
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}

.qt-loading:after {
  animation-play-state: running !important;
}
```